# How to use an existing JS file in a vue project

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I need to use this JS file in my vue3 project.

https://gist.github.com/imolorhe/b31f95e1548ad7d1b233de26267fe21c#file-jungle-js

My JS library is

```
import { Jungle } from "./jungle.js";

async pitchTransform(
    audioBuffer,
    pitchMod 
  ) {
    let ctx = new OfflineAudioContext(
      audioBuffer.numberOfChannels,
      audioBuffer.length,
      audioBuffer.sampleRate
    );

    let source = ctx.createBufferSource();
    source.buffer = audioBuffer;

    let pitchChangeEffect = new Jungle(ctx);
}
```

The application shows this error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/src/js/jungle.js?t=1659194585032' does not provide an export named 'Jungle' (at voiceTransform.js?t=1659199164108:1:10)

What's the recommend way to include and use jungle.js in this setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error is saying, that file has no export named "Jungle". In fact it has none.

You have to export that function manually, by editing that file and appending an `export` keyword:

```js
// ...

export function Jungle(context) {

// ...
```